# Example of Dapper query with n number of Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm building a Dapper query with joins to 8 tables but apparently the Dapper `SqlMapper` only supports 7.

I read in this [article](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/500) that there is an overload that takes n number of types:

```
public static IEnumerable<TReturn> Query<TReturn>(this IDbConnection cnn, 
  string sql, 
  Type[] types, 
  Func<object[], TReturn> map, 
  object param = null, 
  IDbTransaction transaction = null, 
  bool buffered = true, 
  string splitOn = "Id", 
  int? commandTimeout = null, 
  CommandType? commandType = null)
```

Could someone give me a simple example of how to use it?

This is what I used before for joins to less number of tables:

```
var sql = @"SELECT * FROM dbo.ComponentRelationship cr
                        JOIN dbo.ComponentRelationshipType crt ON crt.ComponentRelationshipTypeId = cr.ComponentRelationshipTypeId
                        JOIN dbo.Application fa ON fa.ApplicationId = cr.FromId
                        JOIN dbo.Application ta ON ta.ApplicationId = cr.ToId
                        ORDER BY fa.Name, ta.Name";
            result = connection.Query<ComponentRelationship, ComponentRelationshipType, Application, Application, ComponentRelationship>(sql,
                (cr, crt, fa, ft) =>
                {
                    cr.ComponentRelationshipTypeName = crt.Name;
                    cr.FromName = fa.Name;
                    cr.ToName = ft.Name;
                    return cr;
                }, splitOn: "ComponentRelationshipId,ComponentRelationshipTypeId,ApplicationId,ApplicationId");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/blob/2df6d074e8a38e61c3b441bfcde038ac51a96686/Dapper.Tests/MultiMapTests.cs).

```
            const string sql = @"
                select 
                    rb.Id, rb.Name,
                    u1.*, u2.*, u3.*, u4.*, u5.*, u6.*, u7.*, u8.*, u9.*
                from #ReviewBoards rb
                    inner join #Users u1 on u1.Id = rb.User1Id
                    inner join #Users u2 on u2.Id = rb.User2Id
                    inner join #Users u3 on u3.Id = rb.User3Id
                    inner join #Users u4 on u4.Id = rb.User4Id
                    inner join #Users u5 on u5.Id = rb.User5Id
                    inner join #Users u6 on u6.Id = rb.User6Id
                    inner join #Users u7 on u7.Id = rb.User7Id
                    inner join #Users u8 on u8.Id = rb.User8Id
                    inner join #Users u9 on u9.Id = rb.User9Id";

            var types = new[] { typeof(ReviewBoard), typeof(User), typeof(User), typeof(User), typeof(User), typeof(User), typeof(User), typeof(User), typeof(User), typeof(User) };

            Func<object[], ReviewBoard> mapper = (objects) =>
            {
                var board = (ReviewBoard)objects[0];
                board.User1 = (User)objects[1];
                board.User2 = (User)objects[2];
                board.User3 = (User)objects[3];
                board.User4 = (User)objects[4];
                board.User5 = (User)objects[5];
                board.User6 = (User)objects[6];
                board.User7 = (User)objects[7];
                board.User8 = (User)objects[8];
                board.User9 = (User)objects[9];
                return board;
            };

            var data = connection.Query<ReviewBoard>(sql, types, mapper).ToList();
```